# List of Figures not compiling due to fragile commands

Tags: floats, captions

I have my dissertation written in LaTeX and contains about 40 figures, some of the captions contain short and long format of `acronym` package, and 2 of them contain cites.

Recently I added another one figure with simple text (not any function) as caption and therefore Latex cannot compile the document, with the error appeared in the picture. The figure commands have the shown format:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=14cm]{picture.png}
\caption{Text...}
\label{fig:xx}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

I tried to remove `\listoffigures` command and all works good.
Can anyone tell me what could be wrong?
Do I have to write the graph labels differently?

I tried to remove 1 figure, and the project compiled successfully, but when I remove the caption of the last figure, the problem remains.

It may be someone's fault?

Thank you in advance!
[image]

Comment: Seems hard to tell. Try removing aux file. If it doesn't work, create a minimal working example.

Comment: Maybe unrelated, do not use `center` environment inside `figure`, a `\centering` command will do.

Comment: Thank you all for the information. The problem finally is caused from one figure dimensions, because it was following by another figure... I don't know why, but I will merge these 2 into one figure

Comment: Try adding \protect in front of any fragile macro, or any macro you do not need expanded immediately.  Alternatively, you can use the optional (short caption) argument and remove any problematic text.

Comment: Thank you @JohnKormylo. I think that a problem is elsewhere. When a specific figure has height of 17.5cm it is ok, but when has 18cm the document cannot compile, even if it has margins from the page

Comment: Typically overly large figures simply overrun the margins, although really large figures should use the [p] option.  Again, there is not a lot we can do without an example which shows the problem.  You can even use \rule instead of \includegraphics,

Comment: @JohnKormylo All ok with the figures. I have used the package `adjustbox` and the problem seems to be solved. Thank you for the advices